# ESSVI calibration problem in translating parameter bounds

Tags: options, implied-volatility, calibration, parameter-estimation

I am trying to implement the calibration algorithm presented in the "[ESSVI Implied Volatility Surface](https://assets.ctfassets.net/lmz2w5z92b9u/2dxRCEEtmhqW8eEOo3VX0C/f8ad212fee0a96ffe9cce5b608fc130b/eSSVI_Implied_Volatility_WP_FY20.pdf)" white paper from Factset by Akhundzadeh et al.

The eSSVI model includes 2 variables that must be calibrated to option market IV data slice by slice $(ρ_2,ψ_2)$ with a specific bound constraint to take note of:

$$
|\rho_2 \psi_2 - \rho_1 \psi_1| \leq \psi_2 - \psi_1, \qquad \text{for all } \; T_n > T_1
$$

where $\rho_1$, $\psi_1$ are the parameters obtained from calibrating the previous slice.

Since eSSVI's parameter bounds are dependent on another one of the variables you are calibrating for, you must make $n$ guesses for $ρ_2$ $[ρ_{2i}\ldots ρ_{2n}]$, find the bounds for $ψ_2$ corresponding to guess for $ρ_2$ using the above inequality $[ψ_{2il},ψ_{2iu}]\ldots$ , pass $[ρ_{2i}\ldots ρ_{2n}]$ as a parameter to your minimization function

$$f(ρ_{2i}), \: \text{minimize w.r.t } \: ψ_2,$$
for each, obtain a vector of minimization values $[f(p_{2i})\ldots f(p_{2n})]$, than use the minimum of the vector to center your next $n$ guesses for $ρ_2$.

In the above bound constraint, one must translate the inequality into a lower/upperbound for $ψ_2$ before continuing onto calibration in the next steps. However, you cannot mathematically back this out. Am I misinterpreting the implementation in general, or is there a workaround to this?

(P.S. First time posting so apologies for the non-clarity if found.)

Comment: Pls include more detail about the background of the problem so that one can still understand your question even if the link to the article you have provided a link to is broken.

Comment: ok i fixed it. hopefully this is sufficient enough. @Alper